# Stripping string from a specific character to the end

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column of strings in dataframe e.g. `Warsaw (Warsaw University of Technology)`and want to strip the part that starts in `(` and goes to the end of the string. Parts contained in brackets are diffrent in every row. How can I do that?

Comment: So if the string were `'This (is in the) middle'` you would want the string `'This'` as the result?

Comment: @ALollz exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for regex. To throw away everything from the first occurrence of parenthesis on:

```
df['col1'].str.partition('(') [0]
```

or alternatively you could write a lambda to do:

```
df['col1'].apply(lambda s: s.split('(', 1) [0])
```

Comment: Note these also capture any trailing space before the parenthesis. If you don't want that, regex better

Answer (score 0):

Assuming column named `col1`, the regular expression in `str.extract` matches from start of string up to the occurence of `(`:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

d = {'col1': ['Warsaw (Warsaw University of Technology)','xxxx (yyyy)']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df['col1'] = df['col1'].str.extract('(^[^\\(]*)')

print(df)
```

This prints:

```
      col1
0  Warsaw 
1    xxxx
```